# Which Date Format to use while creating the shipment in BigCommerce

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I am trying to create a new shipment for an Order in `BigCommerce` using `BigCommerce API`.

I am passing all the parameters like this :

```
{
  "order_address_id":8,
  "tracking_number":"",
  "order_date":"Thu, 28 Mar 2013 11:17:22 +0000"," <—I have problem here
  items":
         [
           {"order_product_id":44,"quantity":8},
           {"order_product_id":39,"quantity":0}, 
           {"order_product_id":39,"quantity":0}                              
         ],
  "comments":""
}
```

What I am getting as a response is like :

```
[{"status":400,"message":"The field 'order_date' is not supported by this resource."}]
```

Can anyone tell me what's the correct way of passing the '`order_date`' parameter's value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be a documentation and console bug. I believe that order_date field is not accessible. It should be fixed now.

http://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/orders/shipments

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/console

When you create a shipment, you should not be able to modify the order_date field as it is associated with order creation. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Yaa...You are right..But how fast that field got disappeared ??
Was it you who has update that Page UI?? Thanks :))

Comment: Hi Saran, any way to access Bigcommerce's API console ?